# Is “betterly” a word?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Consider the sentence:

> Sorry for the poorly worded sentence, I could not find a way to word it betterly.﻿

Does the word “betterly” exist? Can it be used in a sentence like that?

Comment: What does Google or a dictionary tell you...?

Comment: ".....I could not find a better way to word it."

Comment: There are exceptions in the English language where "ly" is simply not added. You can find a list here: https://engdic.org/adverbs-that-dont-end-in-ly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because "better" already functions as an adverb. So the -ly ending would be redundant. In your example, then, you would simply say, "Sorry for the poorly worded sentence, I could not find a way to word it better."

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. For some reason, that sounds wrong to me; I think it will be best to simply rewrite the sentence in the rare occasions I come to find myself needing “betterly”.